# How to set the quick and dirty flag in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

Isabelle has a `quick_and_dirty` mode that allows proofs to be skipped with `sorry`. It is enabled by default in jEdit and disabled by default with `isabelle build`. How can I change the setting

- In jEdit (interactively or with a command line parameter),
- For `isabelle build`, from the command line,
- For `isabelle build`, in the `ROOT` file, respectively.

Also, are there other means of asking Isabelle, preferably interactively in jEdit, “What lemmas in the current theory and its parents have been proven using a `sorry`“?

(I am asking this here in the hope that there will always be up-to-date-answers, in contrast to some mailing list posts that I find with google.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any way to achieve your first point (for jEdit), for the other points it should be

```
isabelle build -o quick_and_dirty ...
isabelle build -o quick_and_dirty=true ... # same as the previous command
isabelle build -o quick_and_dirty=false ...
```

and

```
session Foo = HOL +
  options [quick_and_dirty] (*with the same variants as above*)
  theories A B
```

(inside your `ROOT` file), respectively. Or for individual theories, e.g.,

```
session Foo = HOL +
  theories [quick_and_dirty] A
  theories B
```

Also note that command-line options overrule options set in the `ROOT` file.

Comment: Isn’t there a way to set the flag using `ML {* .. *}` inside jEdit?

Comment: I tried `declare [[quick_and_dirty=false]]`, but after that `lemma False sorry` still went through without complaint.

Comment: [NEWS](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/hvg/Isabelle/dist/Isabelle2013/NEWS) says “* Pure: "sorry" no longer requires quick_and_dirty in interactive
mode;”; a bit unfortunate if there is no other way to check for sorrys.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner Maybe worth mentioning that this is already in the part "New in Isabelle2012"of the file you linked.

Comment: How about a plain hyper-search for `sorry` in Isabelle/jEdit?  The same works for `axiomatization`.  The ways to cheat in Isabelle are very limited, so that it is easy to spot the omissions in the text.